# In minecraft I heard creepy music while mining

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A couple minutes ago, I was mining in minecraft and then there was about ten seconds of creepy music. Whats going on? I'm freaking out!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah definitely a dupe.

Comment: herobrine! I knew it!

Answer (score 4):

Incorrect, this sound isn't a soundtrack, but rather an [**ambient**](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience) sound, a sound that's played when you're exploring the wild vast lands of Minecraft.

From the wiki:

> Ambience (sometimes called cave noises) is a set of sounds that
> occasionally play when the player is in ***close proximity to a dark
> cave.***

and

> Despite their name, they are not sounds that one would expect to hear
> inside of a cave, such as falling pebbles or dripping water, but
> rather supernatural noises frequently likened to *demonic*/ *ghostly*
> moans, vehicles, ringing bells and instruments.

Note this:

The Jukebox plays only custom tracks from discs dropped from Creepers.  Ambient sounds can be played whenever you're near a dark cave, but not when you're using a jukebox.  Some people may think that it's a music track, Track 13, which is creepy enough, but not the "ghostly" creepy kind you hear when near a dark cave, which are the ambient sounds, as I mentioned above..

There are also a total of 13 ambient tracks that can play at any time.

Comment: Note to downvoter (@YoungGuilo): If he didn't play any music in a jukebox, then it can only be an ambient sound (he was near dark cave)

Comment: It's confusing/poor form/unnecessary to reply to other answers. Just state what's true and let the votes do the job of showing what is and isn't correct.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Right, got a bit too ahead of myself there.